# MacBook Pro 2011 with fuzzy screen won’t boot

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, recovery, internet-recovery

[image]

I can’t boot into Safe Mode. Also tried recovery mode, but it won’t load. Tried internet recovery mode - no good. ☹️ I'm unsure if this is related to the fuzzy screen (see image above).

I've also tried <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and believe the results were all good.

**How can I proceed to try and get this MacBook to boot up into macOS?**

Bought MBP from a guy on Facebook 3 weeks ago. Lesson learned!!!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to sort this! Absolute stoked.

Visit here for details

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/198711/MacBook+Pro+2011+GPU+Glitch#answer469270